# Adding html and plain text inside div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm recieving a string (it may be either plain text or HTML text) from server, and I need to insert it into a div after that.

I can use `$div.text(textFromServer)` if I know that `textFromServer` is plain text.

If I know that `textFromServer` is html I can do something like `$(textFromServer).appendTo($div)`.

The problem is that I don't know for sure whether `textFromServer` is plain or HTML.

So here's the question: is there a elegant and simple solution for my problem? Or do I have to analyse `textFromServer`?

Comment: Cant you just assume that the text is html and then do `$div.html(textFromServer)`? Even if it is plain text, it will get added fine.

Comment: Just append is OK, I think?

Comment: Check content-type of response coming from server, for 'text/plain' or 'text/html', based on that you can use .html() or .text()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$div.html(textFromServer);
```

Comment: or append in case it should not replace the content

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, but if the OP uses `text()` then s/he replaces the contents.

Comment: I know. Just wanted to be sure it was mentioned

Comment: @mplungjan that is a simpler workaround $div.html($div.html() + textFromServer);

Answer (score 2):

You're describing [jquery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
`$div.html(textFromServer)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If there in no particular reason for knowing about data type (text / html) then you can directly assign the text / html to your div using `[html()][1]` function like

```
$div.html(textFromServer)
```

If you are interested in knowing the type of data `text / html` then you can store the type of your data (text, html) in `hidden` field on `server` and access that in `javascript / jQuery`.